# How to control the maximum number of containers that one Hive query kicks off at the same time

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop-yarn

I have a Hive table that has 1000 files on HDFS, each file is about 128M (one HDFS block is 128M). When I run select count(1) from this table, it will run 1000 mappers in total, which is OK.

What makes things bad is that this Hive query will try to kick off as many mappers as possible at the same time given the cluster resources are available(of course 1000 at most).

This is really bad and ugly, because it may occupy too many resources at the same time, leave other applications no resources to use and have to wait.

My question is how to control the maximum mappers that runs simultaneously?

That is, eg, for 1000 mappers, at any moment， there are 100 mappers at most running at the same time, so that it will not occupy too many resources at the same time(Spark is has such control with `--num-executors and --executor-cores` parameters)

Comment: I am not aware of any way to do this only using Hive. The way to go here is create a yarn queue and limit the resources for the queue. you should be able to use this specific queue for your job to limit the resources

Comment: Thanks @hlagos. I have thought about this approach,but that is really not attractive. especially when other queues are idle, this approach will cause  resource waste.

Comment: By default, YARN will always use all resources so you're not wasting anything unless you implemented a hard limit on your Hive work queue.  But you'd also have to enable preemption to allow new jobs to take resources away from your Hive work queue if you want to prevent other jobs from starving.

Comment: @hlagos tk421, https://jira.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-5583?attachmentOrder=desc

Comment: @Tom, it is interesting, thanks for sharing

Answer (score 2):

As of Hadoop 2.7.0, MapReduce provides two configuration options to achieve this:

- `mapreduce.job.running.map.limit` (default: 0, for no limit)
- `mapreduce.job.running.reduce.limit` (default: 0, for no limit)

[MAPREDUCE-5583: Ability to limit running map and reduce tasks](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-5583?attachmentOrder=desc)